# What is the difference between take somebody to do something and take somebody to something?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Which one is correct ?

1. She took me to a doctor.
2. She took me to see a doctor.

What confuses me is the 'verb' after 'to', I have checked Google, no one uses 'take ....to do something', they just use take....to something.

Comment: When I was small my mother used to take me to have my hair cut, to see a dentist, to get new shoes, and to have my eyes tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you take someone TO DO something, you are completing an action. You are essentially: doing something.
   When you take someone TO something, you are taking them to a location.
2. Both of those phrases are correct. Feel free to use either one. Although, most people would say "see" because it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

In this context "see [a professional]" means "use the services of". We also use "look at" in a similar way. I could go to see someone about a used car, or have a plumber look at my sink, or tell you my aunt is seeing a psychic, or tell the umpire they need to see an eye doctor. After sitting in the waiting room, the nurse says "the doctor will see you now".

Often "see a doctor" or "see my accountant" is the simplest way to say something. For example, "I've got to leave at noon to see my doctor". Because of that we get in the habit of using "see" even in cases where it may not be needed. And even then, it makes the sentence a tiny bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Both are correct and commonly used.**

Googling "took me to see a doctor" with quotes around the phrase will turn up lots of uses of that exact phrase..

Comment: You can lead (or take) a horse to water, but you cannot make him drink.